# remove all lines in a file containing a string from another file

Tags: awk, grep, match, carriage-return

I'd like to remove all the lines of a file based on matching a string from another file. This is what I have used but it only deletes some:

```
grep -vFf to_delete.csv inputfile.csv > output.csv
```

Here are sample lines from my input file (inputfile.csv):

```
Ata,Aqu,Ama3,Abe,0.053475,0.025,0.1,0.11275,0.1,0.15,0.83377
Ata135,Aru2,Aba301,A29,0.055525,0.025,0.1,0.082825,0.075,0.125
Ata135,Atb,Aca,Am54,0.14695,0.1,0.2,0.05255,0.025,0.075,0.8005,
Adc,Aru7,Ama301,Agr84,0.002075,0,0.025,0.240075,0.2,0.
```

My file "to_delete.csv" looks like this for example:

```
Aqu
Aca
```

So any line with those strings should get deleted, in this case, lines 1 and 3 should get deleted. Sample desired output:

```
Ata135,Aru2,Aba301,A29,0.055525,0.025,0.1,0.082825,0.075,0.125
Adc,Aru7,Ama301,Agr84,0.002075,0,0.025,0.240075,0.2,0.
```

Comment: Not clear, please mention more clear examples in your post and let us know then?

Comment: I just updated the question with more exmaples and a sample desired output.  I hope that is clear?

Comment: Could you please try my code once and let me know?

Comment: When you tried your command, what was the actual output?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 - Based on wc -l it didnt delete any lines. @ Benjamin W - It deleted some lines but not all.  I think it only deleted lines for which the string was first?  But hard to say with thousands of lines.

Comment: Do you want to save output in Input_file itself? I will add that code then, try printing it on console first by my code?

Comment: Your example code works exactly as it is supposed for me.

Comment: @ Benjamin W  I created a few test files. If my input file has only one line, it deletes all matching lines. But if there are multiple lines in the input file, it doesn't work for any except the first. I manually checked and some lines that should get deleted don't. I'm baffled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Since OP had carriage characters in his files so adding solution for that too now.

```
cat -v Input_file     ##To check if carriage returns are there or not.
tr -d '\r' < Input_file > temp_file  &&  mv temp_file Input_file
```

Since your samples of Input_file and expected output is not clear so couldn't fully test it, could you please try following.(if you are ok with `awk`), append `> temp_file  && mv temp_file  Input_file` in code to save output into Input_file itself.

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i in a){next}}} 1'  to_delete.csv  Input_file  > temp_file  && mv temp_file  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code too now.

```
awk -F, '                          ##Setting field separator as comma here.
FNR==NR{                           ##checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when first Input_file is being read.
  a[$0]                            ##Creating an array named a whose index is $0.
  next                             ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){              ##Starting a for loop from value i=1 to till value of NF.
     if($i in a){                  ##checking if $i is present in array a if yes then go into this condition block.
       next                        ##next will skip all further statements(since we DO NOt want to print any matching contents)
     }                             ##Closing if block now.
  }                                ##Closing for block here.
}                                  ##Closing block which should be executed for 2nd Input_file here.
1                                  ##awk works on pattern and action method so making condition TRUE here and not mentioning any action so by default print of current line will happen.
'  to_delete.csv  Input_file       ##Mentioning Input_file names here now.
```

Comment: @NKN, also try to check by doing `cat -v Input_file` if you have carriage returns in your file? If yes then you could remove them by doing `tr -d '\r' < Input_file > temp_file  && mv temp_file Input_file`, let me know on same?

Comment: AHHA!  That was the problem.  I thought checked for that initially but I guess they don't show up in some editors. Thank you!