# Remove lines from a text file that contains multiple string patterns from another file in linux

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

The goal is to remove duplicated lines in file2 based on first 3 column values in file1.

tried with modified solution from this post (with single string pattern) but couldn't make it work..

[remove all lines in a file containing a string from another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53404530/remove-all-lines-in-a-file-containing-a-string-from-another-file)

input file1 is tab seperated(5 columns ABCDE):

```
A   B    C    D    E
a   b    c    d    x
aa  bb   cc   dd   xy
aaa bbb  ccc  ddd  xyz
    bbbb cccc dddd xxyz
```

input file2:

```
123|234|aa|ur29842|b|c|234|567
123|234|a|ur29|b|c|234|567
123|234|aa|ur290792|bb|cc|234|567
123|234|aa|ur2909842|bb|ccc|234|567
123|234|aaa|ur29042842|bb|cc|234|567
123|234|aaa|ur2922|bbb|ccc|234|567
123|234|N.A.|ur2922|bbbb|cccc|234|567
123|234|N.A.|ur2922|bbb|cccc|234|567
```

Output:

Remove any line from file2 that has patter like `*|*|a|*|b|c|*|*` or `*|*|aa|*|bb|cc|*|*` or `*|*|aaa|*|bbb|ccc|*|*` or `*|*|N.A.|*|bbbb|cccc|*|*`

The reason that `*|*|N.A.|*|bbbb|cccc|*|*` is in the list is because of the last line in file1 `"    bbbb cccc dddd xxyz"` with first element being empty (tab seperated)

any field in file2 can be N.A..

```
123|234|aa|ur29842|b|c|234|567
123|234|aa|ur2909842|bb|ccc|234|567
123|234|aaa|ur29042842|bb|cc|234|567
123|234|N.A.|ur2922|bbb|cccc|234|567
```

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1 FS $2 FS $3];next} !(($3 OFS $5 OFS $6) in a)' file1 FS="|" files
```

does not capture patterns with N.A. , but don't want to remove all lines with N.A. either.

Comment: @td17: How did your modified solution look like?

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error. A description alone is not enough. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If your real input/output files don't have blank lines between the data lines then [edit] your question so the sample you provided matches that format of your real data.

Comment: @EdMorton blank lines were only to make the input/output look cleaner, although good point.

Comment: It's fine to reference another question for background information if anyone wants to go look at it but make sure your current question stands alone. I can't tell what you're trying to do but maybe others will have more luck.

Comment: understood.. it started from a simple example, but then added too much in input/output file without giving more background. edited post again. appreciate your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS = "[\t|]" }
NR==FNR {
    for (i=1; i<=3; i++) {
        if ($i == "") {
            $i = "N.A."
        }
    }
    a[$1 OFS $2 OFS $3]
    next
}
!(($3 OFS $5 OFS $6) in a)

$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
123|234|aa|ur29842|b|c|234|567
123|234|aa|ur2909842|bb|ccc|234|567
123|234|aaa|ur29042842|bb|cc|234|567
123|234|N.A.|ur2922|bbb|cccc|234|567
```